# Распознование текста с изображения. opencv + pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Необходимо распознать число с картинки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого использую Tesseract-OCR v5.1.0.20220510, и Opencv 4.5.5.64.

Код программы:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("678.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 1000, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary, lang="eng", config="--oem 3 --psm 6")
print(text)
```

Результат выполнения программы: `@deee7297194`
Плохо распознаются нули.
Подскажите как настроить `tesseract` или обработать изображение, чтобы распознавать нули как нули, а не `@, 6, 9, e` и тд.

Comment: Советуют другой распознaватель <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090447/tesseract-ocr-confuses-slashed-0-as-8>

Comment: Предлагают побороться <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475487/why-is-tesseract-number-recognition-not-working-properly>

Comment: Easyocr медленно работает. Я в дальнейшем хочу использовать этот код как часть программы, которая считывает числовое значение с экрана в реальном времени. В принципе для конкретно данного изображения, помогло увеличение его в несколько раз (4 или 10) и изменение настроек в `cv2.threshold` . Но для других изображений, которые могу получить в дальнейшем, такие настройки могут не сработать.